# Script Working In ISE but not in Visual Studio Code, problem with script or with VS Code?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powershell-ise

I'm currently running the following script I've made for practice as I'm attempting to improve my powershell skills, I wanted to start with some basics in case I missed things as I slowly pieced together my knowledge and was calculating circles and other shapes/forms to work with functions a bit.

```
function calculate-circle{ 
$pi = 3.14
[float]$radius = read-host "What is the radius?"

$surface = $radius*$radius*$pi
write-host "The surface area of a circle with radius $radius is $surface"
```

}

Within the Powershell ISE, this executes without a flaw and I'm able to input a radius and come up with calculations.

In VS Code I get the following, after highlighting the entire script and running it using the hotkey for "Run Selected Text In Active Terminal".

```
PS C:\> function calculate-circle{
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At line:0 char:0
PS C:\>     $mypi = 3.14
PS C:\>     [float]$radius = read-host "What is the radius?"
What is the radius?:
PS C:\>     $surface = $radius*$radius*$mypi
PS C:\>     write-host "The surface area of a circle with radius $radius is $surface"
The surface area of a circle with radius 0 is 0
PS C:\> }
At line:1 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
```

What I can't figure out is, is this an issue with my code or is this some quirk of Powershell within VS Code?  I was really enjoying some of the VS Code functionality so I'm a bit miffed.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Terminal: Run Selected Text In Active Terminal` command from the command palette, also accessible as `Run Selected Text` from the `Terminal` menu, submits and executes the selection's lines *individually*, which doesn't work with multi-line snippets such as function definitions.

Instead, use the `PowerShell: Run Selection` command that comes with the PowerShell extension, which is bound to hotkey <kbd>F8</kbd> by default, just like in the ISE; you can also access it from a selection's context menu using the `Run Selection` command.